# Loading AAC audio file in internet explorer 9+ using the html5 audio tag is showing invalid source

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-audio, aac

I want to load an AAC file using the html5 audio tag in internet explorer 9+. The same html file is working fine on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge but showing an "Invalid Source" on internet explorer 11 as you can see in the below picture. MP3 files works fine.

I read that using mp4 as MIME type for AAC will solve the problem. But obviously it did not. 
The AAC file ex2.aac and the html file have the same location, so it is not a source thing.

[Invalid source internet explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjEKL.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <audio controls>
       <source src="ex2.aac" type="audio/mp4">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the problem. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is IE default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a temporary workaround, I suggest you could try to convert the resource from .aac file to mp3/mp4/m4a file. Then, display it.

Comment: Thought so. I used the Naudio library to convert my audio files from AAC to MP3. Thank you anyway!